# Is there any solution for the crash log below?

Tags: ios, flutter, crash, app-store-connect, crash-log

I sent an additional review by updating the app that was in service, but the app review was rejected while receiving the crash log.

I converted the document to a .crash file and figured out the cause below.

```
Hardware Model:      iPad11,6
Process:             Runner [3800]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CCB7BEDF-E4DA-4DDC-A3B0-78243B02B1B4/Runner.app/Runner
Identifier:          com.snowlive
Version:             2.0.5 (16)
AppStoreTools:       14C17
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.snowlive [1469]

Date/Time:           2023-03-20 17:18:57.8904 +0000
Launch Time:         2023-03-20 17:18:54.8593 +0000
OS Version:          iPhone OS 16.3.1 (20D67)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called


Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                         0x1d6ae9e38 __exceptionPreprocess + 164
1   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1cfcf38d8 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   FirebaseFirestore                      0x10565f048 firebase::firestore::util::ObjcThrowHandler(firebase::firestore::util::ExceptionType, char const*, char const*, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) + 112
3   FirebaseFirestore                      0x10565ebcc firebase::firestore::util::Throw(firebase::firestore::util::ExceptionType, char const*, char const*, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) + 20
4   FirebaseFirestore                      0x10563f318 void firebase::firestore::util::ThrowInvalidArgument<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, unsigned long>(char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long const&) + 48
5   FirebaseFirestore                      0x10564e0f0 firebase::firestore::api::DocumentReference::DocumentReference(firebase::firestore::model::ResourcePath, std::__1::shared_ptr<firebase::firestore::api::Firestore>) + 300
6   FirebaseFirestore                      0x105671154 firebase::firestore::api::Firestore::GetDocument(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) + 80
7   FirebaseFirestore                      0x1056905a4 -[FIRFirestore documentWithPath:] + 100
8   Runner                                 0x10443b6bc 0x104430000 + 46780
9   Flutter                                0x107a71948 0x1074e0000 + 5839176
10  Runner                                 0x10443b638 0x104430000 + 46648
11  Flutter                                0x107a71d0c 0x1074e0000 + 5840140
12  Flutter                                0x107a6e2b8 0x1074e0000 + 5825208
13  Flutter                                0x107523858 0x1074e0000 + 276568
14  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1de0ff460 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
15  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1de100f88 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
16  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1de10f7f4 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 928
17  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1de10f444 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44
18  CoreFoundation                         0x1d6b7a6c8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
19  CoreFoundation                         0x1d6b5c02c __CFRunLoopRun + 2036
20  CoreFoundation                         0x1d6b60eb0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
21  GraphicsServices                       0x2104a8368 GSEventRunModal + 164
22  UIKitCore                              0x1d9056668 -[UIApplication _run] + 888
23  UIKitCore                              0x1d90562cc UIApplicationMain + 340
24  Runner                                 0x104437260 0x104430000 + 29280
25  dyld                                   0x1f544c960 start + 2528

Kernel Triage:
VM - pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage


Thread 0 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x213d51674 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x2243f31ac pthread_kill + 268
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x1de164c8c abort + 180
3   libc++abi.dylib                        0x224332b8c abort_message + 132
4   libc++abi.dylib                        0x224322a80 demangling_terminate_handler() + 336
5   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1cfcf9d3c _objc_terminate() + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                        0x224331f28 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 20
7   libc++abi.dylib                        0x224331ec4 std::terminate() + 56
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1de100f9c _dispatch_client_callout + 40
9   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1de10f7f4 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 928
10  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1de10f444 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44
11  CoreFoundation                         0x1d6b7a6c8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
12  CoreFoundation                         0x1d6b5c02c __CFRunLoopRun + 2036
13  CoreFoundation                         0x1d6b60eb0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
14  GraphicsServices                       0x2104a8368 GSEventRunModal + 164
15  UIKitCore                              0x1d9056668 -[UIApplication _run] + 888
16  UIKitCore                              0x1d90562cc UIApplicationMain + 340
17  Runner                                 0x104437260 0x104430000 + 29280
18  dyld                                   0x1f544c960 start + 2528
```

However, I do not know how to analyze the code in thread 0, so please help me which part is the problem.

The related crash log file is also attached.

```
atos -arch arm64 -o Runner.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Runner -l 0x104430000 0x104437260
```

I tried to view the contents using the above command,
This is a state where the content is not properly exposed.

Comment: In frame 4, it appears you've passed Firestore an invalid argument. Look in your code where you access Firestore and pass it arguments. Make certain the data is valid. Your app ultimately threw an exception error meaning there is bad data being passed around. A common example is accessing an item in an array by index that doesn't exist. This is where I would start.

Comment: Thank you so much for checking.

Thanks to this, I was able to see about the direction of the error.

When I run the app with the emulator, the error message below is displayed. Is this the same error?

I also checked Null for GetCurrentUser and GetUserModel, but an error still occurs, so I'm asking for more.

Comment: (lldb) 2023-03-23 23:59:23.271242+0900 Runner[1459:187870] 10.6.0 - [FirebaseCore][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.
<Warning>: Please set a value for FacebookAutoLogAppEventsEnabled. Set the flag to TRUE if you want to collect app install, app launch and in-app purchase events automatically. To request user consent before collecting data, set the flag value to FALSE, then change to TRUE once user consent is received. Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios#disable-auto-events.

Comment: <Warning>: You haven't set a value for FacebookAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled. Set the flag to TRUE if you want to collect Advertiser ID for better advertising and analytics results.
<Warning>: The value for FacebookAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled is currently set to FALSE so you're sending app events without collecting Advertiser ID. This can affect the quality of your advertising and analytics results.

Comment: [Client] Updating selectors after delegate addition failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service with pid 99 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service with pid 99 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process.}
[tcp] tcp_input [C3.1.1:3] flags=[R.] seq=1641707325, ack=1311139794, win=265 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=1641707285, snd_una=1311139731

Comment: [tcp] tcp_input [C3.1.1:3] flags=[R] seq=1641707285, ack=0, win=0 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=1641707285, snd_una=1311139731
[tcp] tcp_input [C5.1.1:3] flags=[R.] seq=516071180, ack=1114586901, win=265 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=516071140, snd_una=1114586838
[tcp] tcp_input [C5.1.1:3] flags=[R] seq=516071140, ack=0, win=0 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=516071140, snd_una=1114586838
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51013/tO7cCVXApCk=/ws

Comment: @trndjc We would like to ask you again about the above error.

Comment: It appears you have forgotten to call `configure()` on the Firestore main object. Look in the documentation for instructions on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This other SO answer helped me: [Flutter iOS Release Crash: Firebase FireStore Util](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74757363/flutter-ios-release-crash-firebase-firestore-util) - for me there was a firestore query that was weirdly going wrong only on Release mode but not on debug mode and I got a very similar crash log to yours.